# How to interpret the [which]: part for the JavaScript expression ( { [which]: o[which] } = bar() );

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I have encountered the following code online:

```
function bar() {
    return {
        x: 4,
        y: 5,
        z: 6
    };
}

var which = "x",
    o = {};

( { [which]: o[which] } = bar() );

console.log( o.x );
```

I understand that this code is an example of the "destructuring syntax" that was introduced in ES6.

I also understand that `o[which]` is searching for a key named `which` in object `o` and if found, return the value for the `which` key.

But I'm not really sure how the `[which]:` part of the expression works.

Comment: See two lines above, namely `var which = "x"`. That should resolve the rest of your confusion.

Comment: @Nit maybe my brain is not working at the moment, or there are gaps in my knowledge, but I just can't get my head around the question at the moment. Cuold you please give me a bit more hint?

Comment: It's a computed property name. Replace with its value `"x"` and you get `({ x: o.x } = bar());`

Comment: Pro-tip: I notice that your posts are very chatty for an experienced user. Please keep them more succinct if you can, as this creates a fair bit of ongoing work for volunteer editors. For example: "Any help would be greatly appreciated", "Thanks in advance for any help", " Could someone please help me out" (etc). Please keep them short and to the point. Thanks!

Comment: @halfer thanks for the advance. Note taken :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [destructuring syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), when you see `from : to`, it means that the value of the property identified by `from` is taken from the thing being destructured and assigned to the variable or property identified by `to`. So looking at that line:

```
( { [which]: o[which] } = bar() );
```

...we see that the value of the property identified by `[which]` is retrieved from the object returned by `bar` and assigned to the property identified by `o[which]`. Since `[which]` is used rather than `which`, it's the *value* of the `which` variable that determines the name of the property taken from `bar`'s returned object, just like when you use brackets syntax when retrieving or setting the value of a property on an object.

The non-destructuring version would look like this:

```
const tmp = bar();
o[which] = tmp[which];
```

Comment: ah, I think i get it. I think in normal object literal, `{a: b}` means assigning value `b` to a property named `a`. But with destructuring syntax, when we encounter `{a: b}`, we are actually assigning the value of `a` to a property named `b` (which is the opposite behavior to normal object literal). I think this is where I got tripped up. Thanks again for your help! Now everything starts to make sense!

Comment: @Thor: Exactly! And although it's tempting to think "well, why make it backward, how silly!" I'm told there were good reasons to do so around nesting and such.

Answer (score 1):

The `[which]:` construct is part of [computed properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) syntax (ES2015+).

Comment: Sort of, but not in the sense you linked to (in an object initializer).